# error when trying to install libtmcg "configure: error: libgmp >= 4.1 is needed"

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've tried installing different libgmp's from ubuntu app center and I tried installing it manually from http://gmplib.org/#DOWNLOAD but I can't get this to configure it's an old library and I'm trying to run it on the latest version of ubuntu but I didn't think I'd have problems but I'm new to trying to use libraries like this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've had these kind of errors installing dependencies before, and I realized that you must to force the installation of such pack having it... you didn't mention the version of your Ubuntu, so I'm assuming you're working with 12.10. But if not you always can look up for the version you are running on.

Just download the pack from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+package/libgmp-dev), of course, depending on your architecture, and after that run `sudo apt-get -f install` in order to force the installation of broken packs.